# Apply check on import statement if project deployment version is less than the SDK version

Tags: ios, swift

I am running a project with deployment version - 9.0. Now while importing a ARKit framework whose minimum deployment version is 12.0 - getting an error.I cant change my application deployment target version so is there any check that can be applied on the import statement which automatically stops loading the framework or something. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the framework with optional status. And then you can check if it is available like this.

[image]

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"ARKit") == nil) { // Not sure about ARKit 
   // the framework is not available

enter code here} elsenter code heree {
   // the framework is avaiable
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried using above mentioned approach. but still getiing error on the import statement - "Module file's minimum deployment target is ios12.0""

Answer (score 0):

Importing should not be an issue. While using it you can put this condition,

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    let view = ARSKView(frame: .zero)
}
```

Comment: Facing issue while importing the SDK - "Module file's minimum deployment target is ios12.0"

Comment: Which SDK? It is unclear what are you importing as you only need this line `import ARKit`. Is this a `Swift` project or cross platform?

Comment: Its a 3rd party SDK, provided by some vendor. yeah it is a native swift project

Comment: Can you share the SDK link?